Peculiar behavior with .CSS file in .NET 8.0 Blazor app
I have noticed a peculiar behavior with .CSS files in .NET 8.0 Blazor.  Here is a summary:

I started development on a .NET 8.0 Blazor project
I created Stylesheet.css for any .CSS classes that were shared among Blazor components.
I moved Stylesheet.css to a subdirectory under wwwroot (\CSS) and changed the path in App.razor (<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/StyleSheet.css" />)
I added another .CSS class to Stylesheet.css.
The new class is not working for any page.

Here is the peculiar part:  When I move Stylesheet.css back directly under wwwroot and set the path back in App.razor (<link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css" />) it works.
It's as if Blazor is still using an old version of the style sheet, without the new class, before I moved the file.  Does anyone have any experience with this and how to fix it?

This doesn't seem to be about puzzles (or a puzzle itself) in the sense meant here.

I added the Programming tag (which I mistakenly thought existed) and it changed it to computer-puzzle.  I will just use the computer-science tag.

Technical issues like browser caching troubles are not puzzles.

"Puzzle" can mean either "thing that is puzzling" or "thing specifically designed to be puzzling, for the fun of figuring out the puzzle". The puzzles we deal with here on Puzzling are the second sort.
